# Export AWS Timestream table to JSON/CSV

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-timestream

I need to export/dump an AWS Timestream table to CSV/JSON but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it. Everything I find seems related to ingesting into Timestream.

I was thinking about AWS Kinesis and but I can't find any existing producers and I was hoping that I wouldn't have to write my own.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up writing a small producer. Turns out it wasn't really that huge of an effort and looking for a proper tool most likely took longer time than actually doing it. =D

Update:
Completed this by moving the code into a Lambda function that runs periodically, producing to a Kinesis Stream, processed by a Kinesis Data Firehose that transforms the JSON to CSV via another Lambda and then writes the content to a S3 bucket.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is there a public repo that shows how to do this @lobbin?

Comment: @AndrewAllison sadly no. I wrote some pseudo code in a gist if that helps? https://gist.github.com/lobbin/73b50555beffb362b31fd536f476d67d